# Is there free, system-wide http/https proxy software for OS X?

Tags: macos, network, software-recommendation, proxy

I need to forward all my traffic trough a HTTP/HTTPS proxy in order to connect to a VPN. I can only connect to that VPN using a HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

Is there something free that I can use to achieve this in OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to a Proxy Server (which is what you're trying to do) you need no special Programm just tell your System to send all the Traffic over the Proxy.

You can do this inside of your Mac's System Preferences under Network

If you need more Information on how i suggest you to read the Official Apple Support Document: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18553

Comment: I can connect to a proxy server, but the default program doesn't set it system wide. For example I want to use GIT or NPM, these command line tools need to be configured to use proxy, they don't pick it from the system settings. Spotify has an option for proxy that needs to be set manually. I need this because I want to connect to a VPN, there is no way to connect to a vpn using a proxy from the Network Preferences, at least I didn't find one.

Comment: I think you are messing things up right now - i thnk what you really looking for is called a VPN Client Programm - there is for Example  OpenVPN (https://openvpn.net) and Viscosity (https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity) at whitch you may have a look. Make shure you do the Settings to pass all the Traffic through the VPN-Tunnel if you wanna use git or npm over VPN - Why you speak about a Proxy i can only guess (maybe do to the Fact that some Companies use a Proxy in combination with the VPN-Server)

Comment: I've tried OpenVPN (Tunnelblick) before but with no luck. I think Viscosity is what I'm looking for. Thank you. I will post results after 3 january.

Comment: It works. I can connect to the VPN using TCP and HTTP Proxy.